# Maintaining scroll position in WebView

Tags: android, webview, scroll

In my application, I have a HTML page loaded in a WebView. I am implementing a switchView button, which loads the same page but in a  different language. I want to maintain the scroll position of the WebView when the language is switched. After some research on SO, I have implemented the following.

This is the first WebView

```
        switchB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.page1);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/try.html");

        switchB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SwitchedView.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("scroll", calculateProgression(webView));
                startActivity(mIntent);             
            }
        });
    }

private float calculateProgression(WebView content) {
        float positionTopView = content.getTop();
        float contentHeight = content.getContentHeight();
        float currentScrollPosition = content.getScrollY();
        float percentWebview = (currentScrollPosition - positionTopView) / contentHeight;
        return percentWebview;
    }
```

With this, I am passing the Scroll to the next Activity which is a WebView loading the same page.

```
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        float scrollp = extras.getFloat("scroll");

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.page2);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/try2.html");

        float webviewsize = webView.getContentHeight() - webView.getTop();
        float positionInWV = webviewsize * scrollp;
        int positionY = Math.round(webView.getTop() + positionInWV);
        webView.scrollTo(0, positionY);
```

This is not setting the scroll Position to the passed scroll position. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/try2.html"); is asynchronous so scrollTo will be executed before the page loads.So you have to call the scrollTo only once the page is loaded successfully. You can achieve this through the following snippet.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override  
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
         webView.scrollTo(0, positionY);
    }  

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
       //error
    }
});
```